# ROF, Auto, Ammo and Shots

Tags: savage-worlds

So from what I understand any weapon with a ROF over 2 without the auto keyword is treated as a full auto weapon and unable to fire in single shot mode.  For example a Gatling gun from the SWD rules has a ROF of 3 and no auto property.

Does this mean that each "shot" actually takes 3 rounds?

In addition according to the ROF keyword a few pages back states that a weapon can fire as many times as its ROF.  So does that mean that a Gatling gun can fire three times?  Each time rolling 3 shooting dice and expending 3 rounds of ammunition?

Further a weapon with ROF 3 and the auto property, can it still attack as many times as its ROF but in single shot mode?  Can an Uzi make three attacks in single shot mode?  or if it makes more than one shot does it need to operate in auto mode expending ammunition equal to its ROF?

Also when an auto weapon makes more than one attack, are those attacks subject to the MAP?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation of the Gatling Gun in SWD, and as the weapon has to fire in full auto mode, it would use 3 rounds of ammunition per 'shot'.

However, your statement about a weapon being able to fire as many times as its ROF is incorrect. Lets take the Gatling Gun as an example. With a ROF of 3 it *can* fire three times, but what this actually means mechanically is that you have three 'shots' - you roll three dice along with the Wild Die and it uses a total of 9 rounds of ammunition. (If you interpreted it your way, the weapon would actually be having 9 shots and use 27 rounds!).

Single shot mode allows you to fire a single shot, using a single round, or a double-tap, which uses 2 rounds of ammunition and gives you +1 to the Shooting and Damage rolls (You still only roll a single Shooting die and a Wild Die though). Certain weapons also allow three round bursts that use 3 rounds and give +2 to Shooting and Damage, and these are indicated as such in the weapons table. Noting that both double tap and three round burst still only allow you to roll a single Shooting die, firing at a greater ROF, which *does* give you more Shooting Dice, requires you to fire in full-auto mode.

If you use a weapon in full auto mode, you don't have to worry about any MAP, but you do add a -2 penalty for the recoil from firing.